# Draw multiple samples using numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Using the numpy function `numpy.random.multivariate_normal()`, if I give the mean and covariance, I am able to draw random samples from a multivariate Gaussian.

As an example,

```
import numpy as np
mean = np.zeros(1000)  # a zero array shaped (1000,)
covariance = np.random.rand(1000, 1000) 
# a matrix of random values shaped (1000,1000)
draw = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance)
# this outputs one "draw" of a multivariate norm, shaped (1000,)
```

The above function outputs one "draw" from a multivariate Gaussian, shaped `(1000,)` (as the covariance matrix is shaped `1000,1000)`).

I would like 200 draws. How does one do this? I would create a list comprehension, but I don't see how to create the iteration.

EDIT: Is there a difference between

```
draw_A = np.random.rand(1000, 1000, 200)
```

and

```
draw_B = [np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance) for i in range(200)]
```

?

Yes, `draw_B` is a list, but are they both 200 independent draws shaped `1000,1000)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you notice the `size` argument in the [docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html)?

For example, this call generates 5 samples from a 3-d distribution:

```
In [22]: np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(3), np.eye(3), size=5)
Out[22]: 
array([[ 1.08534253,  0.70492174, -0.8625333 ],
       [ 0.16955737, -0.89453284,  0.8347796 ],
       [ 0.49506717, -1.18087912, -0.89118919],
       [-0.97837406, -0.42304268,  0.4326744 ],
       [-1.18836816,  1.33389231,  0.23616035]])
```

---

Response to edited question:

- `np.random.rand(d0, d1, d2)` makes `d0*d1*d2` random draws from the *univariate* *uniform* distribution on [0, 1), and returns them in an array with shape `(d0, d1, d2)`.
- `np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size=n)`, where `mean` is an array with shape `(m,)` and `cov` is an array with shape `(m, m)`, makes `n` draws from a multivariate normal distribution, and returns them as the rows of an array with shape `(n, m)`.  Your list comprehension `draw_B` also draws samples from a multivariate normal distribution, with one sample per function call, and it puts the samples into a list instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this. Please see my edit above for clarification. Is `draw_A` the same as `draw_B`?